# C# - запрос через Tor

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, tor

Можно ли в C# отправить HTTP запрос через Tor? Пробовал использовать адрес прокси из сетевых настроек Tor Browser:

```cs
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://2ip.ru/");
request.Proxy = new WebProxy("127.0.0.1:9150");
using (var response = request.GetResponse())
{
}
```

Приведённый код выбрасывает исключение:

> Unhandled Exception: System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (501) Not Implemented.

Вроде прокси отвечает, но, почему-то, с ошибкой. Как заставить его работать?

Comment: Есть подозрение, что 9150 - socks порт, в который HttpWebRequest не умеет.

Comment: @vitidev да, похоже на то. Как работать с ним из C#?

Comment: Искать [какую-нибудь библиотеку](https://nugetmusthaves.com/Tag/socks) под свои требования. Не знаю почему в дотнете нет нативных средств и приходится использовать вот такие костыли, которые либо требуют особого кодирования, либо позволяют IWebProxy, но по факту открывают дополнительный локальный прокси. Но у вас требования просты, так что любой.